# Is there any way to detect if users have enabled custom formatters in the DevTools?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm creating a custom formatter and I would love to not load my extension until the user toggles the setting, and advise them to enable it.

Is there any way to detect that?

```js
// Checking if formatters is an array 
Array.isArray(window.devtoolsFormatters) && window.devtoolsFormatters.length > 0
```

Seems like a wrong assumption, could be that the user installs some extension, but don't have the setting enabled.

Comment: The only better method is to read `Preferences` file in the browser profile directory and check devtools.preferences.customFormatters value, which you can do by writing, registering, and calling a separate [nativeMessaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) utility.

Comment: I'm afraid that my chrome extension shouldn't have permission to read the file system.

Comment: Extension permission to read the `file://` URLs directly is a different thing, and can be enabled on chrome://extensions page for the extension manually.

Comment: Oh, I miss understood the nativeMessaging part. Let me check and see if I can make it work.

Comment: Hey @wOxxOm, I didn't have any success trying with nativeMessaging, could you give me an example on how to read devTools Preferences? Thanks :D

Comment: The file is a standard JSON so there should be no problem to find an example.

Comment: Do you have any extension example that uses nativeMessaging to read the  Preferences JSON file?

Comment: No, I don't, but it seems quite simple except for getting the profile directory path, and even that can be easily circumvented by using a user input to set the path in your extension GUI.

Comment: nativeMessaging seems only to port into other apps, how that would help reading the file?

Comment: See my first comment: "writing, registering, and calling a separate nativeMessaging utility" means you would write a separate utility in any language you like, then register and call it as explained in the documentation for nativeMessaging. You can easily find examples and tutorials for nativeMessaging utilties using a site like google.com or similar.

Comment: I'm not sure how I can "install" a server that plays the utility with nativeMessaging, from the webstore.

As far as I know, the permissions to load some scripts are only on the scope of the browser.

Comment: As you can see in the tutorials, the host app is distributed separately e.g. as a github repo release or any other way you like. It can be an open source script for python/nodejs and so on. All this info should be easy to google up.